# Iterate through list of items to their parent and parent to parent level

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have one requirement to iterate through list of items which has n-level of hierarchy and I would like to get bottom-up elements for the selected item ID.

For e.g. below is the raw data

```
ID         ParentID    ItemName       Category
1          -1          Chai           Breweries
4          -1          Mouse-pad      Electronic
3           1          GST            Taxes
2           1          Spices         
5           4          Mobile         
6           3          My Tax
```

I want to program in C# to iterate and show for e.g. if I pass ID parameter for method 6 then it should print output as below

```
ParentID=3, Name=My Tax, Category=Taxes
```

If I pass ID parameter as 2 then output should be similar

```
ParentID=1, Name=Spices, Category=Breweries
```

please help me in achieving this functionality may be by using Generic collection or any algorithm would help

What I have tried is
I have tried using List and plus LINQ's select many, but with this option I was able to fetch only current item, but not parent category value if current item do not have category associated to it.
Also tried to add recursive method but not sure how to build end output, with recursive we should only get current item.

Okay as per below comments I have used recursive function as below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int categoryId = 202;
        var products = GetProducts();
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == categoryId);

        var output = GetProductRecursively(products, categoryId, string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static string GetProductRecursively(List<Product> products, int parentId, string output)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParentID == parentId);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.Category))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
            {
                stringBuilder.Append($"ParentCategoryID={ product.ParentID}, Name={ product.ItemName}, Keywords=");
                GetProductRecursively(products, product.ParentID, stringBuilder.ToString());
            }
            else
                GetProductRecursively(products, product.ParentID, output);
        }
        else
            stringBuilder.Append($"{output}{product.Category}");
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
    public static List<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        var products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 1, ParentID = -1, ItemName = "Chai", Category = "Breweries" });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 4, ParentID = -1, ItemName = "Mouse-pad", Category= "Electronic" });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 3, ParentID  = 1, ItemName = "GST", Category= "Taxes" });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 2, ParentID = 1, ItemName = "Spices" });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 5, ParentID = 4, ItemName = "Mobile" });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 6, ParentID = 3, ItemName = "My Tax" });
        return products;
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

However, in one iteration it returns Category for parentID, but as it's in recursion it keep on finish its job for earlier iteration hence at this point Category is all time returns ""(empty.string)

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working for you?

Comment: I have tried using List<MyOwnClass> and plus LINQ's select many, but with this option I was able to fetch only current item, but not parent category value if current item do not have category associated to it.

Comment: write that in your question, and state exactly what goes wrong. if you're looking for a one-liner that won't help.

Comment: I would recommend you to look into recursive functions or their alternative with some local state and while loops.

Comment: select many is not applicable here. you need to write down your logic to find the parent with category!=null with possibly a loop or a recursive method. A useful hint is "if you can't think of a logic without Linq, using Linq will NOT make it possible."

Comment: @GuruStron  I have pasted my work, I am finding that recursive method is returns empty string for all time

Comment: @CSharpDev your code does not compile for me. What is `product.Keywords` and `CategoryId`?

Comment: @GuruStron sorry it was copy paste issue, now rectified the code and its running without error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally got it working with correct logic, working code as below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int productId = 6;
        var products = GetProducts();
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == productId);

        var output = GetProductRecursively(products, productId, string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static string GetProductRecursively(List<Product> products, int Id, string output)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == Id);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
            output = stringBuilder.Append($"ParentCategoryID={ product.ParentID}, Name={ product.ItemName}, Keywords=").ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.Category))
        {
            return GetProductRecursively(products, product.ParentID, output);
        }
        else
            output += $"{product.Category}";
        return output;
    }
    public static List<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        var products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 1, ParentID = -1, ItemName = "Chai", Category = "Breweries" });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 4, ParentID = -1, ItemName = "Mouse-pad", Category = "Electronic" });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 3, ParentID = 1, ItemName = "GST", Category = "Taxes" });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 2, ParentID = 1, ItemName = "Spices" });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 5, ParentID = 4, ItemName = "Mobile" });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 6, ParentID = 3, ItemName = "My Tax" });
        return products;
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-recursive solution can look like this:

```
var productId = 6;
var products = GetProducts();

var productDict = products // create dictionary to search for products by id
    .GroupBy(p => p.ID)
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, g => g.First());

var product = productDict[productId];

// create loop state variables 
string category = null; 
var currProduct = product;
// cycle while category not found   
while (category == null)
{
    // or there is no parent product
    if (!productDict.ContainsKey(currProduct.ParentID))
    {
        break;
    }

    currProduct = productDict[currProduct.ParentID];
    category = currProduct.Category;
}

Console.WriteLine($"{category}-{product.ItemName}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, I can only give you a "default" answer for your problem.

To solve your problem, you must implement a function in your classes to get the parent of your instance.

To get the absolute parent (object has no parent itself) you must implement a function which calls itself as long as it has a parent.